# TrueType Font Download Option postscript

Tags: windows, bitmap, driver, truetype, postscript

I am editing a postscript driver, and I need to set the "TrueType Font Download Option" command to Bitmap.

I can not find any command to put in the ppd file that can do this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

[Setting to be edited via PPD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0yGJ.png)

UPDATE: I think I have not been totally clear, so I try to explain the problem in another way.

I am installing a printer with an inf and a ppd file from an HP PostScript driver. Also editing the PPD file with *TTRasterizer and TTDownloadTrueTypeFont command I'm not able to set the "TrueType Font Download Option" to Bitmap. If I apply this choice manually after installation complete it save it

Comment: The PPD file is a PostScript Printer Description, it describes the capabilities of the printer, and may include PostScript fragments to control various  aspects of the printer. It does not to the best of my knowledge control the behaviour of the PostScript producer (the Windows priner driver) It is just barely possible that you can do this in a .wpd file, but I doubt it. Basically you need to do this in the printer driver, not the PPD file. In case its not clear, the PPD file is not the PostScript driver.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, there is no way to set this setting as default unless you change the driver itself and not the .ppd. Right?

Comment: Essentially, yes. It is possible to set the printer driver configuration programmatically, so if you are writing an installer then you could potentially have the installer set the configuration of the driver when it creates the printer. If you're trying to do it all by editing a PPD file then no, you can't change the behaviour of the driver in this regard, because its not a characteristic of the printer.